# using gawk in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, gawk

Hi I want to use gawk in a for loop. Something like this:

```
for i in gawk {print $1} | tr '\n' ' '
do something using $i
```

this isn't working of course. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing backquotes or `$(...)` to evaluate the awk command.

```
for i in $(ls -l | gawk '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' ')
do
       echo $i
done
```

Although the last tr command is not needed since the output from a `$(...)` command implicit will have newlines converted to space in this context.

Answer (score 1):

In the answers offered above, gawk is the sub-routine and bash is the driver.

Another approach is to make gawk the driver using its built in *system* command.

For example:

```
ls | gawk '/^a/ { system("ls -lsa " $1)}'
```

which is handier if (e.g.) you find Bash's string handling tools a little too arcane.

Answer (score 0):

### shell code with awk / gawk example

```
for i in `echo how now | gawk '/how/ { print $2 }'`; do
    echo ...$i
done
```

and

```
$ sh test.sh
...now
$
```